# Unable to send powershell email using php script to outlook using iis windows server 2012

Tags: php, powershell, iis, outlook, windows-server-2012

**Error -:**

> New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80010001 Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED)). At D:\get-process.ps1:5 char:12 +
>   $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo :
>   ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMExcept ion +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman ds.NewObjectCommand
>   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   D:\get-process.ps1:6 char:1 + $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0) +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:)
>   [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull The
>   property 'To' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property
>   exists and can be set. At D:\get-process.ps1:8 char:1 + $Mail.To =
>   "$username" + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo :
>   InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   PropertyNotFound The property 'Subject' cannot be found on this
>   object. Verify that the property exists and can be set. At
>   D:\get-process.ps1:9 char:1 + $Mail.Subject = "New Leave Request" +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation:
>   (:) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
>   The property 'Body' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
>   property exists and can be set. At D:\get-process.ps1:10 char:1 +
>   $Mail.Body = "$username" + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo :
>   InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   PropertyNotFound You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>   At D:\get-process.ps1:12 char:1 + $Mail.Send() + ~~~~~~~~~~~~ +
>   CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull Hello
>   devang_gaur@outlook.com

**get-process.php -:**

```
<?php

    $username = "devang_gaur@outlook.com";

    $psScriptPath = "D:\\get-process.ps1";

    $query = shell_exec("powershell -command $psScriptPath -username '$username'< NUL");
    echo $query;

?>
```

**get-process.ps1 -:**

```
param(
[string]$username
)

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)

$Mail.To = "$username"
$Mail.Subject = "New Leave Request"
$Mail.Body = "$username"

$Mail.Send()

Write-Output "Hello $username <br />"
```

`get-process.php` is the php that is present in root folder `wwwroot` of IIS Windows Server 2012 and from which the PowerShell script `get-process.ps1` is triggered. `Get-process.ps1` contains script for sending the mail

Comment: Format your erroe, it's unreadable

Comment: @Hearner error came like this only

Comment: Ensure the app pool runs under your account and try to set the "Enable the 32-Bit Applications" property to True

Comment: You may also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198239/failed-to-run-outlook-libraries-from-iis

Comment: @jisaak can you provide me an alternative for sending mail using php
I have to extract the values from database and hence send mail containing those values on iis windows server 2012

Comment: just search stackoverflow, there a plenty questions about this topic. Im not  familiar with php

Comment: You asked a very similar question yesterday and received two very good answers that advised you **against** using an Outlook COM object to send mail. I suggest you heed them and use a different approach.

Comment: @arco444 can you suggest me some other approach. I am just one step from project going live. And can i use vbscript instead of powershell

Comment: well you've not really explained what you're trying to actually do. Why don't you just use php? The two answers I referred to both suggested a different approach - have you looked into them?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

Instead, you may consider using a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI. Or any other wrapper around that API, for example, Redemption.